# GCC: which targets support fixed-point types?

Tags: c, gcc, fixed-point

```
$ echo "_Fract x;" | gcc -xc -
<stdin>:1:1: error: fixed-point types not supported for this target
```

[6.16 Fixed-Point Types](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Fixed-Point.html) (emphasis added):

> As an extension, GNU C supports fixed-point types as defined in the N1169 draft of ISO/IEC DTR 18037. Support for fixed-point types in GCC will evolve as the draft technical report changes. Calling conventions for any target might also change. **Not all targets support fixed-point types**.

Question: which targets support fixed-point types?

Extra: Is it documented? How to derive it from GCC's source code?

---

UPD. May be useful: Clang does support fixed-point types via option `-ffixed-point`:

```
$ echo "_Fract x;" | clang -xc - -c -ffixed-point
# OK
```

Comment: low-cost embedded microprocessors and microcontrollers.

Comment: In the GCC source, look for the `--enable-fixed-point` configuration option in "gcc/configure.ac". It can only be enabled for ARM and MIPS currently.

Comment: I wouldn't worry much - it looks mostly useless (you can't change how many integral bits and how many factional bits so it's guaranteed to be bad for almost any specific purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that *GCC 11.2.0* on **AVR** does support fixed-point types. Sizes are:

```
sizeof(signed   short _Fract) == 1
sizeof(unsigned short _Fract) == 1

sizeof(signed   _Fract) == 2
sizeof(unsigned _Fract) == 2

sizeof(signed   long _Fract) == 4
sizeof(unsigned long _Fract) == 4

sizeof(signed   long long _Fract) == 8
sizeof(unsigned long long _Fract) == 8

sizeof(signed   short _Accum) == 2
sizeof(unsigned short _Accum) == 2

sizeof(signed   _Accum) == 4
sizeof(unsigned _Accum) == 4

sizeof(signed   long _Accum) == 8
sizeof(unsigned long _Accum) == 8

sizeof(signed   long long _Accum) == 8
sizeof(unsigned long long _Accum) == 8
```